# Tempered distribution, Schwartz space, functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded, continuously differentiable function with $g'\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for some $1\leq p\leq\infty$. $g$ and $g'$ define tempered distributions by $S_g(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)\, dx$
>
> Show: For every $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ holds $S_{g'}(f)=-S_{g}(f')$

Using integration by parts, I get:

$S_{g'}(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g'(x)\, dx= g(x)f(x)\vert_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x)g(x)\, dx=g(x)f(x)\vert_{-\infty}^\infty-S_g(f')$

I need to show, that $g(x)f(x)\vert_{-\infty}^\infty=0$. Then the formula holds.

How can I proceed?

$\lim_{a\to\infty} g(a)f(a)-g(0)f(0)$ and $\lim_{a\to -\infty} g(0)f(0)-g(a)f(a)$

Do you have a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|f(x)g(x)|\leq\|g\|_{L^{\infty}}|f(x)(1+|x|^{2})|\dfrac{1}{1+|x|^{2}}\leq\dfrac{1}{1+|x|^{2}}\|g\|_{L^{\infty}}\sup|(1+|x|^{2})f(x)|$

Comment: So you stipulated $|f(x)g(x)|$ by a symmetric function. What does that show?

Comment: I don't quite follow? So now $|f(x)g(x)|\leq C(1+|x|^{2})^{-1}$ as we know that $(1+|x|^{2})^{-1}\rightarrow 0$ as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$, so is then $|f(x)g(x)|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yes, but why is then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)=0$?

Comment: We don't need integral for that part, just the boundary value, as what you have written: $f(x)g(x)\bigg|_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So $f(x)g(x)$ is bouned by $0$.

Comment: Yes, boundary value zero.

Comment: But the assumption is that $g$ bounded.

Comment: If $g' \in L^p, p \ge 1$ but we don't assume $g \in L^\infty$ then let $g' = g' 1_{|g'| < 1} + g' 1_{|g'| \ge 1}$ such that $g' 1_{|g'| < 1} \in L^\infty$ is a tempered distribution and $g' 1_{|g'| > 1} \in L^1$ is a tempered distribution. Note $|g(x)|\le |g(0)| +\|g' 1_{|g'| \ge 1}\|_{L^1} +|x| \ \|g' 1_{|g'| < 1}\|_{L^\infty}$ and the same argument applies as in your answer @Cornman

Comment: If $p=1$, then what to do?

Comment: If $g' \in L^1$ then $g$ is bounded

Comment: Right, that's easy, I just missed it.