# Functional analysis, Schwartz space, Integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, schwartz-space

The following question is related to this: [Tempered distribution, Schwartz space, functional analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530258/tempered-distribution-schwartz-space-functional-analysis)

> For $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, $f(x)=|x|$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, $h(x)=\begin{cases} 1, ~\text{for}~ x\geq 0\\ -1,~\text{else}\end{cases}$
>
> holds $(S_f)'=S_h$. Calculate the derivative of $S_h$ (therefore $(S_h)'$).

I am not sure what I have to do.
I have to show, that the functions $(S_f)'$ and $S_h$ are equal.
Hence for every $g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $(S_f(g))'=S_h(g)$. Right?

I tried to evaluate:

$S_h(g)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(x)g(x)\, dx=\int_0^\infty g(x)\, dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 g(x)\, dx$

Using integration by parts, I get to

$xg(x)\vert_{x=0}^{x=\infty}-\int_0^\infty xg'(x)\, dx-(xg(x)\vert_{x=0}^{x=\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^0 xg'(x)\, dx=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} xg'(x)\, dx$

But how do I calculate $(S_f(g))'=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|g(x)\, dx\right)'$, since this is not even a function, and the derivative should be 0?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Feedback on why you downvote is appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not entirely clear to me why: $f$ and $g$ have codomain $\mathbb{C}$ when they are all real valued anyway; and what does derivative of a linear operator mean? I haven't seen such a thing

Comment: It is in the distributional sense. Well, the codomain doesn't matter so much as long as it is bigger than reals.

Comment: I just gave the original task. Sorry when it is still unclear what is meant, but I can not really help. Maybe it is just a typo in the task. I do not know. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}g(x)dx=-\int_{0}^{\infty}xg'(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0}xg'(x)dx=-\int_{\bf{R}}xh(x)g'(x)dx$, note that $xh(x)=|x|$.

So $\left<g,S_{h}\right>=-\displaystyle\int_{\bf{R}}f(x)g'(x)dx=-\left<g',S_{f}\right>=\left<g,S_{f}'\right>$.

And $\left<g,S_{h}'\right>=-\left<g',S_{h}\right>=-\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}g'(x)dx+\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0}g'(x)dx=g(0)+g(0)=2g(0)$.

Comment: Ok, I missed that, so I get $-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g'(x)$. How can I conclude this is equal to $(S_f(g))'$

Comment: I have just edited.

Comment: And how can I evaluate $(S_h)'$? As a hint is given to show, that $d:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, $d(f)=f$' is continuous. Is that needed here?

Comment: There is nothing to calculate: $\left<g,S_{h}'\right>=-\left<g',S_{h}\right>=-\left<g',S_{f}'\right>$. Okay, I got what you meant.

Comment: $-\langle g', S'_f\rangle=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} g'(x)f'(x)$. Is that correct?

Comment: No, but $-\displaystyle\int_{\bf{R}}g''(x)f(x)dx$.

Comment: Are you missing the negative sign. And $-\int_{\mathbb{R}} g''(x)|x|\, dx$ can not be further evaluated, since we are missing what $g''(x)$ is.

Comment: I don't quite follow? Then the trick is to split negative part and positive part and then integration by part. But we don't need that because we have shown that $\left<g',S_{h}\right>=-\left<g',S_{f}\right>$. Anyway, I have just calculated, the answer is $2g(0)$, you may check if I am wrong.

Comment: And $-\left<g',S_{f}'\right>=-(-\left<g'',S_{f}\right>)=\left<g'',S_{f}\right>=\displaystyle\int_{\bf{R}}g''(x)|x|dx$. Yes, there is a minus sign that I have missed for that comment. Anyway, we don't need to compute $\left<g,S_{h}'\right>$ in this way.

Comment: I come to the same value of $2g(0)$. It is $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} g(x)=0$ since $g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ right? So, is now $-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dotso$, or $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dotso$ correct?

Comment: Yes, the boundary values go to zero. I don't quite follow your second question.

Comment: Well, in the comment above you write $-\langle g', S'_f\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g''(x)|x|\, dx$. Further above however we come to $-\langle g', S'_f\rangle=-\int_{\mathbb{R}} g''(x)|x|\, dx$

Comment: Anyway, $-\left<g',S_{f}'\right>=\displaystyle\int_{\bf{R}}g''(x)|x|dx$ is the correct one.

Comment: Oh, excuse me for the inconvenience. I missed, that it is $f'(x)$ further above. It is all clear now. Thank you.